# Simulating and assigning multiple vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, rstudio

I am trying to run some data to compare the Tukey's to Bonferroni's methods, but don't want to simulate the data then assign it to a vector individually.

I am currently doing this but it is too time consuming.

```
v1 = c(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))
v2 = c(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))
v3 = c(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

I am trying replicate now but am not able to make the functions usable.
How do I go about this?

```
> I = 3 #number of populations
> J = 10 #number of samples per
> replicate(I,data.frame(c(rnorm(J, mean = 0, sd = 1))))
$c.rnorm.J..mean...0..sd...1..
 [1]  0.47157860  0.36176156 -0.58902072 -0.14258664  0.35517119 -0.46813092 -0.03242732  0.68066082
 [9] -0.19652503  0.57674030

$c.rnorm.J..mean...0..sd...1..
 [1] -0.9107527 -0.1498868  1.7936493  0.2083297 -0.2178705 -0.8321252 -1.0367427  1.1417998 -0.7209510
[10] -0.1906778

$c.rnorm.J..mean...0..sd...1..
 [1] -1.6571571 -0.3131047  1.3253667  0.1691123  1.7925107  0.5994749  0.5405659  1.1630389  3.1745593
[10]  0.8812708
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you call the `c` function in your code snippets above? It doesn’t fulfil any purpose.

Comment: Do you need a list in return or a `data.frame`. Either way, I would recommend saving them all in a single object.

Comment: @Konrad I'm a newbie to R and from lab classes they said any list should include 'c' to define the vectors

Comment: @3_Kel That’s generally only required when ***c**ombining* different elements into one vector. A single element is a vector on its own (of length 1), no need for the `c`. You can test this: typing `identical(c(1), 1)` in R will yield `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what Jaehyeon Kim proposes above:

```
> vs <- lapply(1:3, function(x) rnorm(100,0,1))
> str(vs)
```

...produces a list of numeric vectors of length 100:

```
List of 3
 $ : num [1:100] 0.367 1.549 0.453 -0.374 -0.105 ...
 $ : num [1:100] 0.254 -0.333 -1.732 -0.213 2.001 ...
 $ : num [1:100] -0.07771 -0.00472 -0.89804 -0.90337 -0.73967 ...
```

When you say, "too time consuming" do you mean to type or to run? This runs really quickly for me.

Comment: The professor thought that it is too time consuming to look at. Thank you by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Below is my trial. In your case, it should be `rep(100, 3)`

```
set.seed(1237)
lapply(rep(10, 3), rnorm, mean = 0, sd = 1)
[[1]]
[1] -0.4448532 -1.9732164 -0.8559826  1.7137530  0.9392717 -1.1769761 -0.9256115
[8]  0.0336911  0.8581240 -0.3075549

[[2]]
[1] -0.02058666  1.81681629 -1.13020054  1.00108987  1.06564415  2.44900776
[7]  0.07325534 -0.60973790 -0.28549277 -1.27718700

[[3]]
[1]  0.71017604  0.14531931 -0.09999525 -1.05494900  0.34294721  0.17487679
[7]  0.02907445 -1.60803324  1.61825097  0.38081074
```

Comment: There is no need in loops. One single `rnorm` call will suffice. For example `split(rnorm(30), ceiling(seq(30) / 10))`